# Regex in Postgres to extract full DN in OpenLDAP

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a program to pass a full string of groups a user in OpenLDAP to **Postgres** query. The string is exactly like this:

```
( 'cn=user1,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg','cn=user2,ou=org2,ou=suborg1,o=myorg','cn=user3,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg','cn=user4,ou=org1,ou=suborg2,o=myorg' )
```

In a query, I only want that to be this in **Postgres**:

```
'user1','user3'
```

Basically extract value of `cn=` when the rest of the string is `ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg`.

`user2` has `ou=org2,ou=suborg1,o=myorg` which is `org2` so it won't match.
`user4` won't match on `suborg2` ,... The variation is unlimited so I like to look for exact match `ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg` only.

I know how to do `replace` but it can't handle unlimited scenarios. Is there a clean way to do this in `regexp_replace` or `regexp_extract`?

Comment: is the query to be run against data stored in a postgresql database? The title & tags don't match and are confusing. what does hive & impala have to do with this problem?

Comment: Sorry it was the wrong title. All in Postgres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the cleanest is by using `SUBSTRING` that can return just the captured substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(strs FROM 'cn=([^,]+),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg') FROM tb1;
```

Here, you match `cn=`, then capture into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `,` with the negated bracket expression `[^,]+` and then match `,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg` to make sure there is your required right-hand context.

Else, you may try a `REGEXP_REPLACE` approach, but it will leave the values where no match is found intact:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(strs, '.*cn=([^,]+),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg.*', '\1') from tb1;
```

It matches any 0+ chars with `.*`, then `cn=`, again captures the non-comma chars into Group 1 and then matches `,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg` and 0+ chars to the end of the string.

See an [online PostgreSQL demo](http://rextester.com/JOK86679):

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
    (strs character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tb1
    (strs)
VALUES
    ('cn=user1,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'),
    ('cn=user2,ou=org2,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'),
    ('cn=user3,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'),
    ('cn=user4,ou=org1,ou=suborg2,o=myorg')
;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(strs, '.*cn=([^,]+),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg.*', '\1') from tb1;
SELECT substring(strs from 'cn=([^,]+),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg') from tb1;
```

Results:

[image]

Note you may leverage a very useful *word boundary* `\y` construct (see [*Table 9.20. Regular Expression Constraint Escapes*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)) if you do not want to match `ocn=` with `cn=`,

```
'.*\ycn=([^,]+),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg\y.*'
   ^^                                     ^^
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regexp_matches()` to get all matching *cn*. Then use `string_agg()` to build a comma separated list of them.

```
SELECT string_agg(ldap.cn[1],
                  ',') cn
       FROM regexp_matches('( ''cn=user1,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'',''cn=user2,ou=org2,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'',''cn=user3,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg'',''cn=user4,ou=org1,ou=suborg2,o=myorg'' )',
                           '''cn=([^,]*),ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg''',
                           'g') ldap(cn);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/17316)

Answer (score 0):

Try regex: `(?<=cn=)\w+(?=,ou=org1,ou=suborg1,o=myorg)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTX5YR/1)

Comment: Hmm I got this strange error in Impala `HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

Comment: I would assume this is because lookarounds aren't supported for postgresql